# How to delete 2 consecutive lines only when both patterns are matched

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Let's consider this simple file:

```
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

I need to remove only those consecutive lines:

```
}
{
```

The result should be:

```
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -e '/^}$/,/^{$/d' file
```

Unfortunately, the last closing curly brace and remaining lines have been removed:

```
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

Any suggestion?

I'm open to any simple solution involving other tools such as awk/perl/... if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed '/^}$/ { N; /\n{$/ d; }' file

{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

To save changes inline:

```
sed -i.bak '/^}$/ { N; /\n{$/ d; }' file
```

---

Alternatively this `awk` would also work:

```sh
awk '/^}$/ {p = $0; next} p != "" {if (/^{$/) {p=""; next} $0 = p ORS $0; p = ""} 1' file

{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'undef $prev, next if $prev eq "}" && $_ eq "{";
           print $prev if defined $prev;
           $prev = $_;
           END { print $prev if defined $prev}' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line.
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`.
- We store the previous line in `$prev`. If the previous line was `}` and the current line is `{`, we forget the previous line and read the next line. Otherwise, we print the previous line *if there was any* (which means we don't print an empty line after the forgotten line). Then we store the current line to $prev and repeat.
- The `END` part is needed to print the last remembered line, if any.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed for `-z`:

```
$ sed -z 's/}\n{\n//' file
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='}\n{\n' -v ORS= '1' file
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '$!N;/^}\n{$/d;P;D' file
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

This two line buffer will also work for other input as in the following test:

```
$ cat test
}
}
{
foo
}
$ sed '$!N;/^}\n{$/d;P;D' test
}
foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS=OFS="\n"}{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' file
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```

Or using `for` loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS=OFS="\n"}{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                if(i == 4 || i == 5) continue; print $i}
}' file
{
bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bla
}
bla bla
bla bla bla
```